# how turn on WebCam in laptop without keyboards fn key on linux?

Tags: linux, debian, webcam, fn-key

my laptop keyboard was broken and i bought a external usb keyboard...
but i need use skype or hangouts and i cannot turn on camera because my new keyboard does not have fn key to control webcam like my laptop keyboard had.

i installed the cheese:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

and the software shows this: "No device found"... after that i need to press fn+f10(in notebook keyboard) to turn on the camera... but this key doesn't work...

So how can i turn on the camera manually?